# Что нужно изменить в js, чтобы модальная форма работала с двумя (и более) кнопками вызова?

Tags: javascript, form, modal

Уважаемые знатоки!
Есть код вызова модального окна на js:

```
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var triggers = document.querySelectorAll(".header-button");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function toggleModal() {
  modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}

function windowOnClick(event) {
  if (event.target === modal) {
    toggleModal();
  }
}

for (var i = 0, len = triggers.length; i < len; i++) {
  triggers[i].addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
}
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

По клику на кнопку (ссылку) со стилем "header-button" выводится,
что нужно изменить в скрипте, чтобы форма вызывалась по клику на ссылки с двумя разными стилями?
Скрипт взял здесь (понравилась работа):
https://codepen.io/luiscolome/pen/qBEdjyX

Спасибо!

Comment: ты и сейчас можешь две формы вывести

Comment: сейчас toggle добавляется **всем** кнопкам с классом `header-button`

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы он работал с кнопками с классом "header-button" и "header-button-2"

Comment: @Алекс можете их через запятую добавить `document.querySelectorAll(".header-button, .header-button-2");`

Answer (score 0):

Задачу можно решить так. Я не понимаю, зачем вам ссылки на модальные окна (это не правильное решение, которое потребует отключения стандартного функционала ссылки).

```js
var triggers = document.querySelectorAll(".button"); 
var modals = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");
var closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".close-button");

function toggleModal() {
  var modalNumber = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-modal")); 
  modals[modalNumber - 1].classList.toggle("show-modal"); 
}
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
  triggers[i].addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
}

for (var i = 0; i < closeButtons.length; i++) {
  closeButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < modals.length; j++) {
      modals[j].classList.remove("show-modal");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

.button{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.modal{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate (-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
}
.show-modal{
  display: block;
}



.close-button{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="header-button">
  <button class="button" data-modal="1">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button" data-modal="2">Button 2</button>
</div>

<div class="modal modal1">
  <button class="close-button">X</button>
  <p>Modal 1</p>
</div>
<div class="modal modal2">
  <button class="close-button">X</button>
  <p>Modal 2</p>
</div>
```

А можна не изобретать велосипед с попап окнами, а использовать готовый html тег `[<dialog>]`[1](https://web.dev/learn/html/dialog/)

Comment: Понравился эффект, но хочется открывать по клику на 2 стиля ссылок:

https://codepen.io/luiscolome/pen/qBEdjyX